# Columns with mixed datatype to be saved as str and jsonb in postgres with python

Tags: python, pandas

I need your advice but don't be horrified with the code below, please.

Situation: I call an API to retrieve the sales information. The response looks like the following:

```
[{'Id': 123,
  'Currency': 'USD',
  'SalesOrder': [{'Price': 2,
    'Subitem': 1,
    'Discount': 0.0,
    'OrderQuantity': 1.0},
         {'Price': 3,
    'Subitem': 2,
    'Discount': 0.0,
    'OrderQuantity': 2.0}],
   'Tax': 18},
{'Id': 124,
  'Currency': 'USD',
  'SalesOrder': [{'Price': 2,
    'Subitem': 1,
    'Discount': 0.0,
    'OrderQuantity': 1.0},
         {'Price': 3,
    'Subitem': 2,
    'Discount': 0.0,
    'OrderQuantity': 2.0}],
   'Tax': 18}]
```

Expected outcome: 1. 'Id' is a stand-alone column; 'Currency' is a stand-alone column. 2. As there could be a different number of 'Subitems', I thought of adding 'SalesOrder' as a json blob in postgres and then, query the json column. Thus, the end result is a postgres table with three columns.

```
id =[]
currency = []
salesOrder = []

#extracting values
for item in df:
  id.append(item.get("Id")
  currency.append(item.get("Currency"))
  salesOrders.append(item.get("SalesOrder"))

#converting to a pandas df
df_id = pd.DataFrame(id)
df_currency = pd.DataFrame(currency)
df_sales_order = pd.DataFrame(salesOrder)

#concatenating cols
df_row = pd.concat([df_id, df_currency, df_sales_order], axis = 1)

#outputting results to a table
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@endpoint/db')
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    df_row.to_sql('tbl', con=conn, schema='schema', if_exists='append', index = False)
```

Doubts: 1. If I try to implement the code above, the 'SalesOrder' list gets split into an X number of columns. Why so? How can I avoid it and keep it together?
2. I am not sure how to proceed with the mixture of data types (str + jsonb). Shall I load 'non-json' columns and then, update the table with the json column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this "df_sales_order = pd.DataFrame(salesOrder)
", just create a column in the "df_currency" like df_currency["sales_order"] and fill it with the "item.get("SalesOrder")". This should solve the issue.

Comment: OK, firstly what I did was overkill. A smart person advised me simply use pd.DataFrame(json). As for the jsonb, I need to convert all array-like cols using df['SalesOrder']=df['SalesOrder'].apply(lambda x:json.dumps(x)) and then, load to the database.

Comment: I've voted to close the question because there are plenty of answers on transferring a dict to a jsonb here.